# subgit user mapping from git to svn uses wrong usernames

Tags: git, git-svn, bitbucket-server, subgit

I am using subgit as svn mirror for our team. user mapping works correctly for all commits done to svn repo (Shows up as same "Author" on git repo), but commits done to git repo show up as different "Author" in svn logs.

I followed the instructions and enabled following properties in my config file:

```
[core]
    shared = true
    authorsFile = subgit/authors.txt
[auth "default"]
   passwords = subgit/passwd
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it.

I had to enable "pre-revprop-change" hook to allow svn:author changes.

Steps:

1. cd
2. cd hooks
3. mv pre-revprop-change.tmpl to pre-revprop-change
4. Add below to new file
5. chmod 700 pre-revprop-change

```
#!/bin/bash
#Sample PRE-REV-CHANGE HOOK

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
USER="$3"
PROPNAME="$4"
ACTION="$5"

 # Allowing user to modify author on revisions
if [ "$PROPNAME" = "svn:author" ]; then exit 0; fi

echo "Enabling subgit to chnage author name for git-svn user mapping" >&2
exit 1
```